# How do I access variables/objects in my whole application?

Tags: python, plugins, importerror

I'm developping a PyQT application. This application is able to load some data from a database, and then do various analysis on these data. All of this works. But as the analyses can be quite complicated, and as a will not be the only user, I had to develop a system with users defined script.
Basically, there's a text editor where the user can program his own small python script (with functions). Then the user can save the script or execute it, by loading the file as a module (within the application).

Here, there a simplified version of my application.

The core of the application is in My_apps.py
and the plugins are here in the same folder i.e. Plugin_A.py

this is the code of My_apps.py:

```
import sys,os

class Analysis(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "I'm the core of the application, I do some analysis etc..."

    def Analyze_Stuff(self):
        self.Amplitudes_1=[1,2,3,1,2,3]
class Plugins(object):

    def __init__(self):
        newpath = "C:\Users\Antoine.Valera.NEUROSECRETION\Desktop\Model" #where the file is
        sys.path.append(newpath)

        Plugin_List=[]
        for module in os.listdir(newpath):
            if os.path.splitext(module)[1] == ".py":
                module=module.replace(".py","")
                Plugin_List.append(module)   

        for plugin in Plugin_List:
            a=__import__(plugin)
            setattr(self,plugin,a)

    def Execute_a_Plugin(self):
        Plugins.Plugin_A.External_Function(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    Analysis=Analysis()
    Plugins=Plugins()
    Plugins.Execute_a_Plugin()
```

and here is an example of the code of Plugin_A.py

```
def External_Function(self):
    Analysis.Analyze_Stuff()
    print Analysis.Amplitudes_1
```

why do I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Antoine.Valera.NEUROSECRETION\Desktop\Model\My_Apps.py", line 46, in <module>
    Plugins.Execute_a_Plugin()
  File "C:\Users\Antoine.Valera.NEUROSECRETION\Desktop\Model\My_Apps.py", line 37, in Execute_a_Plugin
    Plugins.Plugin_A.External_Function(self)
  File "C:\Users\Antoine.Valera.NEUROSECRETION\Desktop\Model\Plugin_A.py", line 8, in External_Function
    Analysis.Analyze_Stuff()
NameError: global name 'Analysis' is not defined
```

but if I add the 2 lines following lines instead of `Plugins.Execute_a_Plugin()`

```
Analysis.Analyze_Stuff()
print Analysis.Amplitudes_1
```

then, it works.

How could I indicate to every dynamically loaded plugins that he has to use the variables/objects already existing in Analysis? Why can't I print Analysis.Amplitudes_1 from within the plugin?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message seems perfectly clear: the name "Analysis" doesn't exist in the namespace of the `Plugin_A` module you imported, and so `External_Function` cannot access it.

When you import the `Plugin_A` module, it doesn't get access to the names in the namespace of the importing module, `My_apps`. So it cannot "see" the instance of the `Analysis` class that you created there.

A simple solution to this is to change the signature of `External_Function` (and other related functions), so that it can take an instance of the `Analysis` class:

*`Plugin_A.py`*:

```
def External_Function(self, analysis):
    analysis.Analyze_Stuff()
    print analysis.Amplitudes_1
```

*`My_apps.py`*:

```
   ...

   def Execute_a_Plugin(self):
       plugins.Plugin_A.External_Function(self, analysis)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    analysis = Analysis()
    plugins = Plugins()
    plugins.Execute_a_Plugin()
```

Note that I have altered the naming so that the instance names don't shadow the class names.

Comment: Ok, this solution works well ! Maybe a last point. In my application, there are 6 important classes. Is there an easy way to automatically pass them in plugins functions without naming all of them individually? (could I include them in *kargs or **kwargs). I tried ARG=[Analysis,Class2,Class3,Class4,Class5,Class6], then 

       `def Execute_a_Plugin(self):`
           `plugins.Plugin_A.External_Function(self,Analysis,Class2,Class3,Class4,Class5,Class6)`

I can call `plugins.Plugin_A.External_Function(self,*ARG)` and it works <br/>. But i would prefer to have *ARG in the function definition.

Comment: @Vantoine. You could have a container class that has all the other class instances as attributes, and then pass the container to the plugins.

Comment: What about this? (It worked, but it's maybe not the cleanest way...) : At the begining of the program, i add     `Class_List=[Navigate,Requete,Analysis,Main,Infos,Mapping] 
for Class in Class_List:
     setattr(__builtin__,Class.__name__,Class)`                          then, when loading a plugin:      `setattr(sys.modules[__name__],plugin,__import__(plugin))`          ,with plugin being the name of the loaded plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import your module. Add the following on top of Plugin_A.py

```
from My_apps import Analysis

A = Analysis()
A.Analyze_Stuff()
print A.Amplitudes_1
```

Comment: If I re-import Analysis in Plugin_A , it will overwrite Analysis.Amplitudes_1 value when the module is launched. Is there an other way to link Analysis variable to Plugin_A variables, without reinitializing all the core's modules?

Comment: I'm not sure, if I understand you. `Analysis` is a class, so you have to define an object of it first. Compare my edit. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Let's say I launch my real application. As here, the Analysis class is initiated at the beginning. I get my data, do my stuf, analyze them with various functions located in the Analysis class (like Analyze_stuff() here), all of this in the core of my application. I finally get a list of amplitudes, which is an object of Analysis. Here it would be Analysis.Amplitudes_1. All of this were basic functions. Now, I want to perform a very specific operation on these data (Analysis.Amplitudes_1).

Comment: So I wrote a script, called Plugin_A, and execute it from within the application (by using exec() on the script code). Plugin_A needs the previously created Analysis.Amplitudes_1 list, but that is what doesn't work. And of course, if a do a `from My_Apps import Analysis` in the script itself, it will overwrite the value before using it